# I wanted to validate the part of json matches with Karate response

Tags: karate

```
* def responseJson = 
"""
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "cars": {
  "car1": "Ford",
  "car2": "BMW",
  "car3": "Fiat"
},
 "bikes": {
   "bike1": "b1",
   "bike2": "b2",
   "bike3": "b3"
 }
}
"""
```

Question: I wanted to compare portion of json. I was trying to utilize Karate's "contains" dsl but was not successfull. below code ref:

```
def expectedJson1 =
"""
{
 "car1": "#string",
 "car2": "#string",
 "car3": "#string"
}
"""

* def expectedJson2 =
"""
{
 "car1": "#string",
 "car2": "#string"
}
"""
* def expectedJson3 =
 """
 {
  "car1": "#string"
 }
  """
  * match responseJson contains '#(^expectedJson1)'
  * match responseJson contains '#(^expectedJson2)'
  * match responseJson contains '#(^expectedJson3)'
```

I do not want to use json path for key/value comparison as actual response json is pretty complex to read. So wanted to do partial match randomly possible.

Comment: this question is closed. ask a new question and keep it simple please